# How do I count the number of comments and avaluations for each user with for-each? XSLT (user = utilizador)

Tags: xml, xslt, dtd

I have this xml:

```
<Loja>
<utilizadores>
<utilizador user_id="_28565748">
    <username name="catarmoa99"/>
</utilizador>

<utilizador user_id="_29478382">
    <username name="margaridaaat"/>
</utilizador>

<utilizador user_id="_22478383">
  <username name="diogomiguel85"/>
</utilizador>

<utilizador user_id="_293665789">
        <username name=" davrodrigues"/>
</utilizador>
</utilizadores>
<vendedores>
...
</vendedores>
<produtos>
    <produto product_id="_12578987" vendedor_produto="_28565748">
        <nome>Computador HP_54000j</nome>
        <comentários>
            <comentário id="_c01" data="" utilizador="_29478382" avaliação="5">O serviço foi eficaz, cumprindo os prazos.</comentário>
            <comentário id="_c03" data="" utilizador="_29478382" parent="_c01">Chegando em muito boas condições.</comentário>
            <comentário id="_c02" data="" utilizador="_29478382" avaliação="5">Muito bom produto.</comentário>
            <comentário id="_c04" data="" utilizador="_29478382" avaliação="5">Fantástico serviço!</comentário>
            <comentário id="_c05" data="" utilizador="_29478382" avaliação="5">Vou comprar mais!</comentário>
        </comentários>
</produto>
</Loja>
```

I have these xslt and the output is xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <!--<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="starter-template.css"/>-->
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.users.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="starter-template-users.css" />
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center" class="my-4">Users</h1>
<xsl:for-each select="Loja/utilizadores/utilizador">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-8">
<div class="card mb-4">
<img class="card-img-top" src="foto user_id = _28565748.jpg" alt="Card image cap"/>
<div class="card-body">
  <h2 class="card-title"><xsl:value-of select="nome"/></h2>
  <p class="card-text"><b>ID: </b><xsl:value-of select="@user_id"/></p>
  <p class="card-text"><b>Username: </b><xsl:value-of select="username/@name"/></p>
  <p class="card-text"><b>Telephone: </b><xsl:value-of select="telefone"/></p>
  <p class="card-text"><b>Comments: </b><xsl:value-of select="count(//comentário)"/></p>
  <p class="card-text"><b>Avaluations: </b><xsl:value-of select="count(//comentário/@avaliação[/../@utilizador =//utilizador/@user_id])"/></p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</xsl:for-each>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My question is... I want the number of comments that each user did. How do I do that with for-each?
...................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Your edit changed the whole question. This is against the rules of SO. If you have a new question, create one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XSLT-1.0 solution achieves this using three templates:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/AMAZINGSTORE">
    <sellers>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="seller"/>
    </sellers>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="seller">
    <xsl:element name="seller">
      <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="@username" /></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="product"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="product">
    <xsl:element name="product">
      <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<!DOCTYPE AMAZINGSTORE SYSTEM "StoreInfo.dtd">
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sellers>
  <seller name="migueltavares">
    <product>Origem</product>
    <product>Lincoln No Bardo</product>
  </seller>
  <seller name="tosilva">
    <product>A Estranha Ordem Das Coisas</product>
  </seller>
  <seller name="artursoares73"/>
</sellers>
```

P.S.: I did use `<xsl:element name="...">` instead of `<...>content</...>` to to be more explicit.

Comment: @CatarinaMota: I just used `xsltproc` on Linux.

Comment: There is no way in which `<xsl:element name="product">` is superior to `<product>`. None. It's just more to type and more to read. My recommendation would be to avoid this clutter. (The idiomatic approach would be `<xsl:copy>` in this case.)